# Angular 5 External JSON config returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular, config

In my assets i've got a config.json file with an apiUrl

```
{
    "apiUrl":"https://api.example.com"
}
```

I've got multiple environments, but one of them needs to be able to be altered after the build.

```
import * as config from '../assets/config.json';

export const environment = {
    production: true,
    appTheme: "blue-theme",
    apiUrl: config.apiUrl
    appName: "App",
};
```

in my typings.d.ts i've got

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

When i do console.log(config) I get:

```
{
    apiUrl:"https://api.example.com"
}
```

But when i do console.log(config.apiUrl) I get:

```
undefined
```

Can someone tel me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look here or a different method https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938411/1160794

Answer (score 1):

### How to retrieve Json data

**using by  `node`**

```
const config: any = require('../assets/config.json');
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    appTheme: "blue-theme",
    apiUrl: config.apiUrl
    appName: "App",
};
```

---

**Using by  `http`**

[How to extract JSON data from http.get in Angular 2 properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173762/how-to-extract-json-data-from-http-get-in-angular-2-properly)

[How to fetch JSON file in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406043/how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2)